# Directory lookup for the file failed with the operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, migration, osql

I am trying to re-create a database (MyDB) from one SQL server (**Source**) to another one (**Target**). **Source** is located on my local machine and is SQL Server 2014. **Target** is located on a remote machine and it's SQL Server 2012. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. On my local machine I go to SQL Server Management studio, I right click on MyDB and go to Tasks--> Generate Scripts.

   2. There I select "Script entire database and all database objects".
   3. I click Next and on the next page, under Advanced, I select "Schema and data".
   4. That generates a SQL file (scripts.sql) that contains the definition for MyDB.
   5. Then I use the following osql command to re-create the database on **Target**:

> osql -S target -d master -E -i scripts.sql -o output.log

6. After execution is finished I get this error in the log file "output.log":

> 1> 2> 1> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6> 7> 8> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server
>   Target,    Line 2 Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf"
>   failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the
>   path specified.). Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Server Target, Line 2
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created.
>   Check related errors.
>   1> 2> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Server
>   Target, Line 1 User does not have permission to alter database 'MyDB',
>   the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that
>   allows access checks. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Server Target, Line
>   1 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Here are the first few lines of "scripts.sql":

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [MyDB]    Script Date: 4/12/2016 4:30:20 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [MyDB]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'MyDB', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf' , SIZE = 513024KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 262144KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'MyDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1317504KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 131072KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [MyDB].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON
```

I do have the file MyDB.mdf at the location it's complaining about on **Source**, but not on **Target**. There is no directory "MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER" on **Target**. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For those interested in the solution to this, the problem was that there was no "MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER" directory on **Target** because it's on a different version of SQL Server, namely 2012. What I had to do was create the directory manually and it started working after that.

Answer (score 2):

### If Target DB is on RDS

If the target DB is a MS SQL Server running on AWS RDS, then you have to change the file locations of the data and log files. RDS by default saves them in a D: drive that is not accessible by the user. `D:\rdsdbdata\DATA`

So for example:

You generate a .sql script from your source database and script has the file path `FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf'` *(Path Taken from question)*. Take this script and before running it in the RDS instance, you have to change it to `FILENAME = N'D:\rdsdbdata\DATA\MyDB.mdf'` and then the file system will allow it to run.